# Writing and proving a predicate logic word problem

Tags: proof-verification, predicate-logic

I was assigned some homework for an intro class that covers predicate logic. I got through it, but I'm unsure if I have set it up and proven it correctly. The book were using is rather vague on the set-up process and just provides some examples, but not thought process/explanation. The explanation on some of the inference rules is also not clear enough, so I wanted to make sure that I'm using these correctly. Furthermore, our professor told us that when using (∃x) it should be by an ∧, and when using ∀x it should be followed by an →. I tried to adhere to that as I best I could to formulate the logic.

The Problem:

> Using predicate logic and the symbols {F(x),C(x),O(x,y),D(x)}, prove the
>   following argument: Every farmer owns a cow. No dentist owns a cow. Therefore
>   no dentist is a farmer.

My set-up and proof:

```
(∃y)[C(y)∧(∀x)(F(x)→O(x,y))]∧(∀x)(∀y)[D(x)∧C(y)→O(x,y)']→(∀x)[D(x)→F(x)']

1.  (∃y)[C(y)∧(∀x)(F(x)→O(x,y))]                    hypothesis
2.  (∀x)(∀y)[(D(x)∧C(y))→O(x,y)']                   hypothesis
3.  C(a)∧(∀x)(F(x)→O(x,a))                          1, existential instantiation
4.  C(a)∧F(x)→O(x,a)                                3, universal instantiation
5.  (∀y)[(D(x)∧C(y))→O(x,y)']                       2, universal instantiation
6.  D(x)∧C(a)→O(x,a)'                               5, universal instantiation
7.  D(x)→C(a)→O(x,a)'                               6, exportation
8.  C(a)                                            4, simplification
9.  F(x)→O(x,a)                                     4, simplification
10. O(x,a)'→F(x)'                                   9, contraposition
11. D(x)→F(x)'                                      7, 10 hypothetical syllogism
12. (∀x)[D(x)→F(x)']                                11, universal generalization
```

**EDIT:**

After reworking the problem based on the suggestions I received, I have come up with the following:

```
(∀x)[F(x)→(∃y)(C(y)∧O(x,y))]∧(∀x)(∀y)[(C(y)∧O(x,y))→D(x)']→(∀x)[D(x)→F(x)']

1.  (∀x)[F(x)→(∃y)(C(y)∧O(x,y))]                hyp.
2.  (∀x)(∀y)[(C(y)∧O(x,y))→D(x)']               hyp.
3.  (∀x)[F(x)→(C(a)∧O(x,a))]                    1, existential instantiation
4.  F(x)→(C(a)∧O(x,a))                          1, universal instantiation
5.  (∀y)[(C(y)∧O(x,y))→D(x)']                   2, universal instantiation
6.  (C(a)∧O(x,a))→D(x)'                         2, universal instantiation
7.  (D(x)')'→(C(a)∧O(x,a))'                     6, contraposition
8.  D(x)→(C(a)∧O(x,a))'                         7, double negation
9.  D(x)→C(a)'∨O(x,a)'                          8, De-Morgan
10. (C(a)∧O(x,a))'→F(x)'                        4, contraposition
11. C(a)'∨O(x,a)'→F(x)'                         10, De-Morgan
12. D(x)→F(x)'                                  9, 11 modus ponens
13. (∀x)[D(x)→F(x)']                            12, universal generalization
```

I've decided to stick with this answer. The problem was extra, but through struggling with it and re-writing I have a better feel for some of the rules. At this point I feel like I just need to clear up some things about this topic in general. Thank you for the help/suggestions.

Comment: Does every farmer own the same cow? Because that is what $\exists y[C(y)\land...]$ means. You want $\forall x(F(x)\rightarrow \exists y(C(y)\land O(x,y)))$.

Comment: No, but if I use (∀y) wouldn't that end up meaning all cows are owned by a farmer? By using ∃y I was going there is at least one thing that is a cow and for all things that are farmers, then O(x,y).

Comment: Okay, I didn't see the rest of your comment/edit. I see how it being written like that makes more sense.

Comment: $\exists y\forall x$ is very different from $\forall x\exists y$. For example, it is true that $\forall x\exists y(y=x+1)$. It is not true that $\exists y\forall x(y=x+1)$.

Comment: When I read the statements out loud, what you said makes sense. But looking at it, I don't understand why the order would matter. The quantifiers are being applied to (y=x+1) in both cases.

Comment: Because the value of $y$ depends on what $x$ is, so you can't assert there is a single $y$ which works for all $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using predicate logic and the symbols $\{F(x),C(x),O(x,y),D(x)\}$, prove the following argument: Every farmer owns a cow. No dentist owns a cow. Therefore no dentist is a farmer.
>
> $(∃y)[C(y)∧(∀x)(F(x)→O(x,y))]∧(∀x)(∀y)[D(x)∧C(y)→O(x,y)']→(∀x)[D(x)→F(x)']$

You have written: "If there is **some cow that every farmer owns**, and all dentists *don't own* all cows, then all dentists are not farmers."  Which, while true, is not what you were asked to say.

Because, $(∃y)[C(y)∧(∀x)(F(x)→O(x,y))$ means there is at least *one* cow that is co-owned by all farmers.  The same cow.

You wanted $(\forall x)(\exists y)[F(x)\to (C(y)\wedge O(x,y))]$ "everyone who is a farmer owns something which is a cow."